# Get fields from custom object

Tags: sobject

I have a string which is a name of sObject. I converted the string to a sObject. Now I want to get the fields from the object. When I try to access the fields from sobject (contact) i am getting error

> Field expression not allowed for SObject

I want to get the fields from the sObject how it is possible.

Comment: Can you post the code use used when trying to access the fields for your SObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes when you use `Sobject.FieldAPIName`  then only you receive error

> Field expression not allowed for SObject

Because you cant access the value this way.

### Solution

You need to use SObject `get()` method to get the value... **[Sobject Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)**

like

```
Sobject.get('FieldAPIName')
```

This will give you the value of that Field i.e. `FieldAPIName`..